# How to overlay dot plots on the boxplots with groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, point

I'm trying to create a simple graph to compare test scores by both the classes and the first or second test.

```
a <- data.frame(Name = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"),2),
                Class = rep(c(rep("class1",3), rep("class2", 3), rep("class3", 3)),2),
                Test = c(rep("first",9), rep("second", 9)),
                Score = c(80, 70, 50, 60, 80, 90,
                          75, 85, 50, 75, 85, 98,
                          85, 76, 50, 75, 68, 72)
)
g <- ggplot(a, aes(x = Class, y = Score, fill = Test))+
geom_boxplot()
```

This created expected boxplots categorized by class and the first/second test.
Then, I tried to overlay the dotplots on the boxplots.

```
g <- g + geom_point()
```

But this created dot plots for each class with the first and second test scores on the same lines[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Z43A.png).
How can I distinguish the first and second test scores like I did in the boxplot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I belive you can easily distinguish with this:

```
g + geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center', dotsize=0.5, binwidth=5)
```

[image]

edit: grouping the dot and box:

```
g + geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center', dotsize=0.5, binwidth=5, position = position_dodge(width = 0.9))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying. I know what you show is one way, but I want to plot the green and red dots on the green and red boxplot, respectively.

Comment: Ah, I see. you can just add "position_dodge" 
`g + geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center', dotsize=0.5, binwidth=5, position = position_dodge(width = 0.9))`

Comment: Yeah, I appreciate your kindness!

Answer (score 0):

Is this the sort of layout you're looking for??

```r
library(ggplot2)

a <- data.frame(Name = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"),2),
                Class = rep(c(rep("class1",3), rep("class2", 3), rep("class3", 3)),2),
                Test = c(rep("first",9), rep("second", 9)),
                Score = c(80, 70, 50, 60, 80, 90,
                          75, 85, 50, 75, 85, 98,
                          85, 76, 50, 75, 68, 72)
)

g <- ggplot(a, aes(x = Class, y = Score, fill = Test))+
  geom_boxplot()

g + geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.75))
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Do mark as answered to close this question